# Order Django admin change list column by output of __unicode()__ method

Tags: django-admin, sorting

Here's part of my Django app's **models.py**:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    birth_year = WideYear(null=True, blank=True)
    birth_year_uncertain = models.BooleanField()
    death_year = WideYear(null=True, blank=True)
    death_year_uncertain = models.BooleanField()
    flourit_year = WideYear(null=True, blank=True)
    flourit_year_uncertain = models.BooleanField()
    FLOURIT_CHOICES = (
        (u'D', u'Birth and death dates'),
        (u'F', u'Flourit date'),
    )
    use_flourit = models.CharField('Date(s) to use', max_length=2, choices=FLOURIT_CHOICES)
    index_entries = models.ManyToManyField(IndexEntry, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.personname_set.filter(default_name__exact=True):
            name = z(self.personname_set.filter(default_name__exact=True)[0])
        else:
            name = u'[Unnamed person]'
        if self.use_flourit == u'D':
            dates = '%s - %s' % (z(self.birth_year), z(self.death_year))
        else:
            dates = 'fl. ' + z(self.flourit_year)
        return '%s (%s)' % (name, dates)

class PersonName(models.Model):
    titles = models.CharField(max_length=65535, null=True, blank=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    middle_names = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    post_nominals = models.CharField(max_length=65535, null=True, blank=True)
    default_name = models.BooleanField()
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s, %s %s' % (self.surname, self.first_name, self.middle_names)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("titles", "surname", "first_name", "middle_names", "post_nominals", "person")
        unique_together = ("default_name", "person")
```

and here are the corresponding parts of my app's admin.py:

```
from reversion.admin import VersionAdmin

class PersonNameInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PersonName
    extra = 1

class PersonAdmin(VersionAdmin):
    radio_fields = {"use_flourit": admin.HORIZONTAL}
    inlines = [PersonNameInline]

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

In the admin, this produces a change list as follows:

[image: screencap]
<sub>(source: [sampablokuper.com](http://misc.sampablokuper.com/misc_pics/change_list_screencap.png))</sub>

As you can see, although the change list *populates* each row of the Person column with the output of the __unicode()__ method of the **Person** class, it does not *order* the rows of that column by the __unicode()__ method of the **Person** class.

***How can I make it do so?***

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django ordering is done in the database level. Unless you store the result of your unicode function in the DB, django is not going to be able to natively return results ordered in that fashion.

Storing an ordering value in the DB is probably the most expedient way to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for this, Paul. I had reached the same conclusion, but was hoping I might be mistaken! This then begs the question of *how* to store the ordering value in the DB. Maybe with the aid of a post_save signal? I'm working on this now, but if anyone knows the best way, please post it; I'm sure you'll save me (and anyone else looking for advice about this topic) quite a bit of time! Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, a post-save is probably the way to do it. I also wish there was a more convenient way to do this, but your next best bet is going to involve getting query sets from the DB, sorting them in python, and then sending them back to the admin interface which is way more work than it's worth.

Comment: I tried to put the code for this in a comment here, but that didn't work. So I've created [another answer][1] to hold it.

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406745/order-django-admin-change-list-column-by-output-of-unicode-method/1412299#1412299

Answer (score 1):

Just hit the same problem, and I found the following link useful. Instead of sorting by unicode, it tries to sort by multiple columns, which may help solve the problem:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2110/

Answer (score 0):

Following [Paul McMillan's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406745/order-django-admin-change-list-column-by-output-of-unicode-method/1406788#1406788), I added the following line to the class definition of **Person**:

```
ordering_string = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

I also put the this above the **PersonName** definition in models.py:

```
def post_save_person_and_person_name(sender, **kwargs):
    person_name = kwargs['instance']
    person = person_name.person
    if person.ordering_string != unicode(person)[0:254]:
        person.ordering_string = unicode(person)[0:254]
        super(Person, person).save()
```

and put this below the **PersonName** definition in models.py:

```
post_save.connect(post_save_person_and_person_name, sender=PersonName)
```

So far, so good.

I think I might be able to improve on it by replacing the save() call above with a queryset update() . I'd welcome suggestions on that front!

Comment: Cool. Usually the thing to do is to edit the original question with more info like this. Glad it's working out for you!

Comment: Ah, OK. I'll do that next time. I can't say I find the workflow on StackOverflow enirely intuitive, and I guess the community is simultaneously evolving its own conventions too, as in this case. Thanks for correcting me!

Comment: Yeah, I agree there are definitely a few rough spots in the UI, but the community is really fantastic for finding answers quickly.